# Configure AspNetCoreModuleV2 in process for multiple virtual apps in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have ASP.NET Core applications hosted on Azure App Services as two virtual applications in the same App Services instance. The main site app is hosted at `/` and the blog application at `/blog`. I would like to use AspNetCoreModuleV2 with the InProcess hosting model. However, it fails to start up and I see this error in the event log:

```
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2"/>
<EventID>1008</EventID>
<Level>1</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
...
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>
Only one inprocess application is allowed per IIS application pool. Please assign the application '/LM/W3SVC/170746742/ROOT/api' to a different IIS application pool.
</Data>
<Data>Process Id: 20236.</Data>
<Data>
File Version: 12.2.18296.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2. Commit: 61f1a70784dc0a32cf98f8ddd169c0293b0390ab
</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

How can I run multiple virtual applications in App Services using the InProcess hosting model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. The error info in the event log has answered,

> `<EventData>
>   <Data>`
>   Only one inprocess application is allowed per IIS application pool. Please assign the application '/LM/W3SVC/170746742/ROOT/api' to a different IIS application pool.
>   `</Data>`

In your scenario for running multiple virtual applications in the same Azure WebApp, only one app can run in the hosting model as `in-process`, others can be configured in `web.config` file as `out-of-process` via [`Kestrel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) , as below, please see more details at here [`ASP.NET Core Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

> Note:  hostingModel="**OutOfProcess**"
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
>     <system.webServer>
>       <handlers>
>         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
>       </handlers>
>       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
>                   arguments=".\MyApp.dll" 
>                   stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
>                   stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
>                   hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
>     </system.webServer>
>   </location>
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're right. I wish we could have an application pool per virtual app or something to make it work.

Comment: Using a separate app pool solved my problem but would be better if when publishing it would just add hostingModel="OutOfProcess" for non-InProcess applications instead of leaving it blank on web.config.